# reescribir una url eliminando el final

Tags: .htaccess

Necesito crear una regla en `htaccess` para que elimine el final de algunas `url`:

```
/productos/refrigeracion/expositores-refrigerados/vertical/expositor-refrigerado-vertical-cst-1600-3-puertas-led-detail?tmpl=component&print=1
```

Necesito quitar `?tmpl=component&print=1` para que se dirija a

```
/productos/refrigeracion/expositores-refrigerados/vertical/expositor-refrigerado-vertical-cst-1600-3-puertas-led-detail
```

¿Cómo tendría que hacerlo?
He probado varias formas y no me funciona o me da error.

Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. La verdad es que ando un poco perdido con htaccess. Sigueindo lo que me indicabas he puesto esto pero me reenvia al index:

```
RewriteEngine On RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&print=1$ RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Que puedo hacer para que se vaya a la url que hay antes de `?tmpl=component&print=1$`

---

Muchas gracias por tu pronta respuesta. La verdad es que ando un poco perdido con htaccess.
Sigueindo lo que me indicabas he puesto esto pero me reenvia al index:

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^tmpl=component&print=1$
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]

Que puedo hacer para que se vaya a la url que hay antes de ?tmpl=component&print=1$

Comment: Bienvenido a [es.so], te sugiero que hagas el [tour] y, de paso, ganar tu primera medalla. También es importante que leas [ask] y [mcve] para poder mejorar tus preguntas y que sean bien recibidas por la comunidad, de esta manera favoreces a que los usuarios las respondan y te ayuden. ¿Qué has probado? ¿Qué errores te daba? Si das más información es más fácil ayudarte :)

Answer (score 0):

Un signo de interrogación literal en la URL marca el inicio de la cadena de consulta, por lo que puede probar si la cadena de consulta contiene algo y redirigir si lo hace. Usando Apache mod_rewrite en .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} .
RewriteRule (.*) /$1? [R=301,L]
```

Los ? (signo de interrogación) al final de la sustitución RewriteRule elimina efectivamente la cadena de consulta de la URL reescrita al crear una cadena de consulta vacía. El signo de interrogación en sí no aparece en la URL resultante. Si estás en Apache 2.4+, puedes usar la marca QSD en su lugar (Query String Discard).

Si solo necesitas hacer ésto para una URL específica, cambia la RewriteRule en consecuencia:

```
RewriteRule ^(residential-properties/projectname/)$ /$1? [R=301,L]
```

**[AQUI](https://ayudawp.com/todo-sobre-htaccess/)** tienes mucha más info.

Saludos

Comment: Hola he puesto esto siguiendo tus indicaciones